# phonegap javascript template explanation seeked usage of the this keyword

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am not sure what to call this question since its kinda big.

I downloaded the code from Phonegap, the basic template.

There is a code example:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

Why "app.receivedEvent('deviceready');" and not "this.receivedEvent('deviceready');"

I tried to understand but i just cant get it.

Anyone able to explain this to me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments explain why.

You need to notify the app that the device is ready. The `this` object in the context is the event itself.

It would be like calling `event.receivedEvent`.

You nee to notify the application that the device is ready, hence the `app` call.

Edit: to further clarify, `this` is the context of `app` with the app object except in the `onDeviceReady` function. The `bindEvents` function runs this code:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
```

Which binds `onDeviceReady` to an event via `addEventListener` which changes the context of `this` from `app` to the `event`.

This means, you cannot call methods from `app` via the `this` keyword with that changed context. Hope this helps clarify a bit more.

Edit 2: see this code for some demonstration: http://jsbin.com/UGerika/1/edit?html,js,output

```
    // http://jsbin.com/UGerika/1/edit?html,js,output
    // Demonstrates the scope of 'this' variable once a
    // function is bound to event receiver.

    var app = {
      var1: function(){
       return "i am this"; 
      },

        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
          alert('bindevents');   
          this.onWindowClick();
        },

      onWindowClick: function() {
        // in this case, this.var1 is perfection valid
        // 'this' is still scoped to 'app' object.
        alert(this.var1);   
      }

    };


    var app2 = {
      var1: function(){
       return "i am this"; 
      },

        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
          alert('bindevents');   
          document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onWindowClick, false);
        },

      onWindowClick: function() {
        // in this case, this.var1 is invalid
        // 'this' is scoped to 'mousedown' event.
        // we would have to call app2.var1
        alert(this.var1);   
      }

    };
```

Comment: yea but there is also: this.bindEvents();   and bindEvents is a function.  I dont understant why its ok to call this.bindEvents() like that, and not the other.  The comment it self i dident get it.  :(

Comment: Sometimes you want to work with the context of a function, you do that with the `this` keyword. In this case, you want to work with another context, the `app` context, which means you need to work with the proper variable for that context.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the app context could be vs context of a function?  :-)

Comment: Thanks i got it now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with phonegap app. But from the comment I understand that the context of the function  onDeviceReady is the actual event and not the app itself. So you need to explicitly use app instead of this to refer the actual app.